# How to Pandas split a column conditionally based on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

below is my Pandas Dataframe

```
Id        IsDef     Data                                       
1         Y         1a
2         N,N,N,Y   2a,2b,2c,2d
3         N,Y       3a,3b
```

How do I split it as below using Pandas? Prioritizing only 1st two entries of 'Yes' and 'No'

```
Id        DataY_1   DataY_2   DataN_1  DataN_2                                     
1         1a        NULL      NULL     NULL   
2         2d        NULL      2a       2b
3         3b        NULL      3a       NULL
```

Comment: What have u tired...please share the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten columns to `DataFrame`:

```
from itertools import chain

d = df['Data'].str.split(',')
isdef = df['IsDef'].str.split(',')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Data' : list(chain.from_iterable(d)), 
    'IsDef' : list(chain.from_iterable(isdef)), 
    'Id' : df['Id'].repeat(d.str.len())
})
```

Then use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per groups and filter out all rows without first 2 by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 2
df['g'] = df.groupby(['Id','IsDef']).cumcount()
df = df[df['g'] < N]
```

Then reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and add missing categories by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html). Last is flattened `MultiIndex` in columns by `f-string`s:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Y','N'], np.arange(N)])
df = df.set_index(['Id','IsDef', 'g'])['Data'].unstack([1,2]).reindex(columns=mux)
df.columns = [f'Data{i}_{j+1}' for i, j in df.columns]
print (df)
   DataY_1  DataY_2 DataN_1 DataN_2
Id                                 
1       1a      NaN     NaN     NaN
2       2d      NaN      2a      2b
3       3b      NaN      3a     NaN
```

Comment: Hi, i'm getting the error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
at d = df['Data'].str.split(',') 
. But type(df['Data']) is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>